# Build MySQL query insert data from 3 tables to the 4. table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 source tables and 1 target table. I want to copy datas from source tables to the target table chained from 1.table->2.table->3.table->4.table.

Here is an example:

```
table1: 
| id | column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 |
|  1 | Asia    |  China  |         |         |

table2:  
| id | columna | columnb | columnc | columnd |
|  1 |    1    | Fruits  |         |         |

table3:  
| id | columnz | columy  | columnx | columnw |
|  1 |    1    |  Sweet  |         |         |

table4:  
| id | columnA | columnB | columnC | columnD | columnE | columnF | columnG |
|  1 |    1    |         |         |         |         | Yangmei | http:// |
```

I need this result:

```
table4:  
| id | columnA | columnB | columnC | columnD | columnE | columnF | columnG |
|  1 |    1    | Asia    |  China  | Fruits  |  Sweet  | Yangmei | http:// |
```

Group name and 1.subgroup in the table1 under column1 and column2, the 2.subgroup is in the table2 columnb where columna = table1 id, the 3.subgroup is in the table3 columnb where columnz = table2 id, the article in the table4 columnF  and the article url in the columnG where columnA = table3 id.

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's an `UPDATE` statement using a `JOIN` to get the values.

```
UPDATE table4 AS t4
JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t1.id = t4.columnA
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.columna = t4.columnA
JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t3.columnz = t4.columnA
SET t4.columnB = t1.column1, t4.columnC = t1.column2,
    t4.columnD = t2.columnb, t4.columnE = t3.columny
```

Comment: This doesn't quite "solve" the complete problem. You should add the `insert` statement too.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood that he was modifying table 4.

Comment: Thank you Barmar for your advice, the idea is good, but your script is not! The right way is think about the JOIN-s: not all is = t4.columnA only the "JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t3.columnz = t4.columnA" other JOIN-s is "JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t3.columnz" and "JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t1.id = t2.columna"
After that change need to change the query order like this:
<pre>
UPDATE table4 AS t4 
JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t3.columnz = t4.columnA 
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t3.columnz 
JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t1.id = t2.columna 
SET ....
</pre>
Need to change "columnA = t3.columny" to columnE = t3.columny!
Thank

Comment: It doesn't matter if you join on the column from the previous table or join them all with `table4`, since the joining columns are all equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, this might solve your issue:

```
insert into table4 (cola,colb...)
values((select cola from tab1),(select cola from tab2)...)
```

I haven't checked the code, but I think this can help.

Comment: Since `table4` already contains rows and it just needs some columns filled in, you need to `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`.

Comment: Looking at the above answer, I thought you were looking for an insert. I will try to update my answer soon